# Одинаковый slug у произвольного типа и таксономии

Tags: wordpress

Зарегистрировал произвольный тип:

```
add_action( 'init', 'exercises' );

function exercises() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Упражнения',
        'singular_name' => 'Упражнение',
        'add_new' => 'Добавить упражнение',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новое упражнение',
        'edit_item' => 'Редактировать упражнение',
        'new_item' => 'Новое упражнение',
        'all_items' => 'Все упражнения',
        'view_item' => 'Открыть упражнение',
        'search_items' => 'Искать упражнение',
        'not_found' =>  'Упраженение не найдено.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине нет упражнений.',
        'menu_name' => 'Упражнения'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments'),
        'taxonomies' => array(  ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_post_type('exercises', $args);
}
```

Также зарегистрировал таксономию для категорий:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_category_exercises');

function add_category_exercises() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Рубрики',
        'singular_name' => 'Рубрика',
        'all_items' => 'Все рубрики',
        'edit_item' => 'Изменить рубрику',
        'update_item' => 'Изменить рубрику',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую рубрику',
        'new_item_name' => 'Добавить новую рубрику',
        'menu_name' => 'Рубрики'
    );

    register_taxonomy('cat_exercises', array('exercises'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'exercises/muscle',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    ));
}
```

Так советуют делать на англоязычном stackoverflow. Если записи произвольного типа работают, то если перейти на страницу таксономии возвращается 404 ошибка.

То есть по идее должны получится такие ссылки:

*site.com/exercises/example-post* - ссылка поста работает, всё нормально.

*site.com/exercises/muscle/press* - ссылка не работает, возвращает 404 ошибку.

Вопрос: почему не работает и возвращается 404 ошибка?

P.S. Обновление ссылок сделал.

P.S. Для @SeVlad
Вот также пример такой реализации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чём  вопрос?

Comment: @SeVlad то что возвращается 404 ошибка, и почему она возвращается и не работает.

Comment: по какому адресу 404?

Comment: @SeVlad site.com/exercises/muscle/category

Comment: В вопрос напиши

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаюсь что так советуют  на SO

`'slug' => 'exercises/muscle'`

и именованию существующими термами ("рубрики")

Слаг не может быть со слешем.

> Вопрос: почему не работает и возвращается 404 ошибка?

Так всё верно -  `category` - это слаг родной ВПшной таксономии. Что она делает в `site.com/exercises/muscle/category`.

В общем и код не правильный и хотелка иметь слаг таксономии непонятно где.

И да. В ВП одинаковые слаги быть не могут. *(Вернее могут, но очень специфично и делать на это ставки не нужно)*

Матчасть:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

В помощь генератор:  https://generatewp.com

Comment: Как раз таки такое решение я и нашёл в одном из ответов на SO. При этом всё у меня получилось. Посоветовали регистрировать таксономию до регистрации произвольного типа. Тогда ссылки работают так как надо.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Где ты нашел такой слаг?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55462/taxonomy-archive-with-same-slug-as-custom-post-type

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev и где там подобная ересь? `'slug' => 'exercises/muscle'`

Comment: И если тебе нужно связать свою каастомную таксономию с кастомным типом, то это нужно прописывать в коде (функциях). Но ты об этом в вопросе не указывал.

Comment: То есть по коду не видно что-ли? Также в том ответе:

Comment: Change your URL structure to be less confusing and make more sense by nesting them:

example.com/our-people/johnsmith
example.com/our-people/jobs/managers

do this by setting the rewrite value when you register your jobs taxonomy ( it's okay to use a / )

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev ,блин ЧПУ от слага не отличаешь?... короче не может быть такого слага в коде.

Comment: вы хотите сказать что такой код не правильный 'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'exercises/muscle',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true ??

Comment: Но при этом верно работает и именно так советую делать

Comment: А что не ясно в " и код не правильный и хотелка иметь слаг таксономии непонятно где."? Родной таксономии!  Родной слаг!

Comment: Тогда в таком случаи я не могу доверять Вашему мнению. При том что на данный момент всё работает как надо при таком решении и куча сайтом где описан такой вариант. Также как и приведенном вопрос на SO именно такое решение.